# c++ Invalid pointer dequeued from free list

Tags: c++, memory-management, std

I have a for loop where I keep copying a section of a vector to another vector and do some process until it traverses the original process and then ran in to this error: `malloc: *** error for object 0x60c0000005e0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

I think it's due to the way of extracting the subvector:

```
vector<float> sub (order, 0);
for (vector<float>::iterator it = data.begin(); it < data.end() - order; it++) {

    std::copy(it, it + order, sub.begin());

    ...some other processing
}
```

I also tried creating a new vector object inside the for loop every time and also replaced `std::copy()` with a for loop but still got the same error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
            sub[i] = *(it + i);
}
```

I just want the behavior like something in Python as: `sub = data[i: i + order]`. What is the correct way to do that? Thanks in advance.

The whole function

```
void MarkovChain::initTransitionMatrix(vector<float> data) {
    vector<float> sub (order, 0);
    for (vector<float>::iterator it = data.begin(); it < data.end() - order; it++) {
//        std::copy(it, it + order, sub.begin());
        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
            sub[i] = *(it + i);
        }
        int key = statesToKey(sub);
        if (transitionMatrix.find(key) == transitionMatrix.end()) {
            transitionMatrix.insert(std::make_pair(key, vector<int> (numState, 0)));
        }
        int nextIndex = getIndexForState(*(it + order));
        transitionMatrix[key][nextIndex] += 1;
    }
}
```

The goal of this function is to compute the transition matrix of a Markov chain. `order` in my code refers to how many previous sample needed in order to make the prediction, for example `data` may be of length 20 and `order` is 3. Then I try to record the counts of a specific state following a sequence with the length of `order` like how many times an 'A' state follows the sequence 'D' 'C' 'B'. So the terminate condition for the loop I set is `it < data.end() - order` since I want to  record the final element of `data`

Comment: Is `order` exactly half the size of `data`? Otherwise, I don't think `sub` should have a size of `order`. And this is why you have to post an example that compiles and shows the problem if you want meaningful answers.

Comment: Or conversely, the loop condition should not be `data.end() - order`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is somewhere else in your code. Either `data` was already corrupt before entering this function, or `statesToKey(sub)` corrupts the `sub` vector. The original code with `std::copy` works like a charm: https://www.onlinegdb.com/SycyVD5jf

Also note that your solution with `std::copy` is more efficient than the one proposed by @Arkady, as it doesn't involve allocating and deallocating the memory multiple times.

Comment: That is, if you want it to ignore the last element of `data`.

Answer (score 1):

this should work.

```
for (vector<float>::iterator it = data.begin(); it < data.end() - order; it++) 
{
    vector<float> sub (it, it+order);
}
```

Comment: It seems this cannot resolve the problem, still getting the same error

Comment: You are sure the problem is with sub ? Could you create a simple test code and show point to the exact problem ?